# Is Printer Available?

Tags: ios, cordova, printing, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and Cordova to build an hybrid application. In the application I allow the user to set the IP of his printer. Now when I print I need to make sure that the printer is online. Is there a way to do a quick test to see if the printer is online?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE. You wouldn't do this through your editor. It needs to be done by your running app on the user's device.

Comment: Sorry, I explained it wrong. Yes, It needs to be done through the app. I am just not sure how to do this through code.